# 3D soil profile from borehole information

Tags: 3d-analyst, model, profile, subsurface, borehole

I wonder what would be the best option if I want to build a 3D soil model in GIS from borehole information? Basically I want to generate several 3D soil layer surfaces. Can everything be done using the 3D Analyst extension of ArcGIS for Desktop, or am I better off using specific add-on programmes like GSI3D (Lithoframe Viewer) and Rockworks?

Comment: 3D Anlyst is not suitable for this type of work. It is possible with extreme effort and some programming skills but you are much better off using a specialized software that can handle boroheles/drill holes, assays and allows building if lithologies from such data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a specific add-on programme, look at [The Subsurface Geology of Brussels, Belgium, Is Modeled with 3D GIS](http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/winter0506articles/subsurface-geology.html) with 3D Analyst.

[image]

or [Modeling the Terrain Below](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0312/modeling-the-terrain-below.html) (3D Borehole tools)

Answer (score 2):

To build the boreholes, I would recommend this tool which is intended to be used with the 3D Analyst extension of ArcGIS for Desktop:

[image: www.geol-gis.ch]

You can set the coordinates of the starting points, azimuth and tilt of the borehole, the depth of the layers interfaces, a water level and some related data through bar charts parallel to the borehole axis.

http://www.geol-gis.ch/en/borehole-3d

Then, if you want to generate the layers surfaces, you can either draw a polygon manually or draw points at the layers interfaces and build a TIN from these points.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what data you have, if you just need to grid a surface gis is ok, if you need to interpret the subsurface you need special software...

Comment: This could use a bit more detail, like which "special software", and maybe some suggestions on how to apply it. If your answer depends on data types, you could consider asking for that in a comment against the question.